# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

Quando este código é rodado todo junto dá este erro, mas se ele estiver formatado com as quebras de linhas ele roda normalmente, como corrigir?

Erro:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this

Código em questão:

```
var Recorder = function(source){ this.context = source.context; if(!this.context.createScriptProcessor){ this.node = this.context.createJavaScriptNode(4096, 2, 2); } else { this.node = this.context.createScriptProcessor(4096, 2, 2); } var AW = new Worker('./scr/js/crypto_worker.js'); this.node.onaudioprocess = function(e){ if (!Config.audioRecording) { return; } AW.postMessage({data:{ taskID: 'record', buffer: [ e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0), e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(1) ] }}); } this.record = function(){ Config.audioRecording = true; Config.analyserCallbackSTA(); } this.stop = function(){ Config.audioRecording = false; } this.clear = function(){ AW.postMessage({data:{ taskID: 'clear' }}); } this.getBuffers = function(cb) { Config.audioCallback = cb; AW.postMessage({data:{ taskID: 'getBuffers' }}); } this.exportWAV = function(callback, type){ Config.audioCallback = callback; type = 'audio/wav'; if (!Config.audioCallback) { Config.audioRecorder.stop(); console.error(dT(), 'Failed in generation of audio/wav'); safeConfirm({ type: 'ERROR_SYS', noBar: true, message: User.LANGUAGE.ERROR_AUDIO_SYS }); return; } AW.postMessage({data:{ taskID: 'exportWAV', type: type }}); } AW.onmessage = function(e){ if(Config.audioCallback) { Config.audioCallback(e.data); } } source.connect(this.node); this.node.connect(this.context.destination); };
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nesse código tem diversas [expressões de função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13365) dentro de uma função construtora (que também foi declarada como expressão). A estrutura desse código é mais ou menos assim:

```
var Construtor = function() {
    this.a = function() {

    }
    this.b = function() {

    }
};
```

Quando você minifica o código, fica com um trecho assim:

```
... = function(){}this ...
```

E é aí que está o erro. Expressões de função sem `;` no final (após o `}`) têm altas chances de darem problema em código minificado (ver [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3341)). Isso só ocorre com expressões de função, não com qualquer bloco `{ }`. Por exemplo, isto é válido:

```
if(1){}this
```

Mas isto é um erro de sintaxe:

```
var f=function(){}this
```

Moral da história: coloque ponto-e-vírgula no final das expressões de função:

```
var Construtor = function() {
    this.a = function() {

    };
//   ^   
    this.b = function() {

    };
//   ^
};
```

Comment: Muito muito obrigada! Mais algo que entrou em meus conhecimentos

Comment: Que bom, fico feliz quando minhas respostas contribuem com o conhecimento das pessoas!