# Por que a troca de valores via desestruturação não funciona se não usarmos ponto e vírgula?

Tags: javascript, variáveis, característica-linguagem, sintaxe

Sabemos que o ponto e vírgula é opcional em JavaScript, inclusive sempre prefiro não usá-lo. Se eu quiser fazer uma troca de valores entre duas variáveis, via desestruturação, posso fazer:

```js
let a = 11;
let b = 22;
[a, b] = [b, a]
console.log(a, b)
```

Esse trecho de código funciona exatamente como o esperado e realiza a troca de valores entre as as variáveis `a` e `b` sem a necessidade de uma variável auxiliar.

No entanto, caso eu não use ponto e vírgula na declaração das variáveis que participarão da troca, como abaixo, ocorre um erro:

```js
let a = 11
let b = 22
[a, b] = [b, a]
console.log(a, b)
```

Simplesmente dá erro. A mensagem do erro é "`Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'b' before initialization`". Por que esse comportamento ocorre quando não usamos o ponto e vírgula na declaração das variáveis?

Comment: @PedroHenrique em JS é sim, a linguagem insere automaticamente, o problema nesse caso, é que o `;` está sendo inserido no lugar errado

Comment: achei esse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59905264/destructed-array-swap-not-working-as-expected) que explica o motivo do erro

Comment: Bom, a documentação oficial diz que o ponto e vírgula é, sim, opcional. https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza que é algo que já falei várias vezes, teve gente que até negativou minha resposta porque eu falei que deve usar sempre o `;` mesmo que não precise. Realmente é opcional, só não quer dizer que será colocado no lugar certo, o compilador não é capaz de resolver todos casos. Existe uma onda de pessoas ensinando não por `;` em JS, o que é um erro, uma hora estoura. Essa á a típica situação disso: https://i.stack.imgur.com/td2dx.jpg https://g1.globo.com/sp/sao-paulo/noticia/2019/07/10/prefeito-e-primeira-dama-de-osasco-tem-alta-12-dias-apos-explosao-de-fogueira.ghtml

Comment: Opcional é, mas é sempre bom usar.

Comment: Não vejo motivo para negativar, é opcional, as vezes não funciona como esperado, orientar a colocar sempre que possível é um bom conselho

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza vai responder? Continuando o comentário anterior: ignoráncia+ arrogância é uma combinação explosiva, a pessoa vê acontecendo certo uma vez, outra, mais uma, depois outras, vai sempre dando certo e ela passa acreditar que seja verdade, ou seja, ela cria *fake news* pra si mesma. Porque ela não quer ver o que é certo. Sim, pode não por `;`, mas não deve, a linguagem não foi bem definida para isso funcionar sempre. Então não faça exceção, faça sempre o certo, o que é garantido que funciona. Não foi o que aconteceu em Osasco. Pq funcionou antes acreditaram que nada aconteceria.

Comment: @Maniero não vou responder, coloquei o comentário apenas para mais informações, não sei como formular uma boa resposta  para esse caso

Answer (score 15, accepted):

É justamente por esse tipo de coisa que o ponto-e-vírgula sempre deve ser utilizado. Para evitar esse tipo de erro no código. É um tipo de preguiça que pode causar erros.

---

Em JavaScript, toda declaração (*statement*) deve ser terminada por um ponto e vírgula. Para garantir que esse sempre seja o caso, mesmo que o programador esqueça dessa finalização, a linguagem possui um mecanismo chamado "inserção automática de ponto e vírgula", ou "*automatic semicolon insertion*", o que torna a inserção da maioria dos pontos e vírgulas algo opcional. Então esse mecanismo basicamente corrige erros de sintaxe, inserindo os pontos e vírgulas que o programador omitiu.

A especificação da linguagem determina que a inserção automática de ponto e vírgula deve seguir três regras para acontecer. Em um grande resumo, as [três regras](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-automatic-semicolon-insertion) determinam que será inserido um ponto e vírgula nos seguintes casos:

1. Quando o programa, encontra um *token* ofensivo (*offending token*), um ponto e vírgula é inserido. Um *offending token* é basicamente algo que não é correto de acordo com a gramática da linguagem.
2. Quando o fim do fluxo de entrada de *tokens* é encontrado (o fim do programa), um ponto e vírgula é inserido.
3. Quando um `return`, `continue`, `break` ou `throw` for encontrado e depois encontrar-se um [`LineTerminator`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#prod-LineTerminator) e um *restricted token*, como um `}`, um ponto e vírgula será inserido antes do *restricted token*.

Tentei resumir da melhor forma possível. Consulte a [especificação](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-automatic-semicolon-insertion) para mais detalhes sobre esses passos.

Com isso, é possível dizer que no seu exemplo:

```js
let a = 11
let b = 22
[a, b] = [b, a]
```

Um ponto e vírgula será inserido depois de `11`, já que `l` (que segue `11`) seria considerado um *offending token* (primeira regra). Contudo, um ponto e vírgula não será inserido depois de `22` automaticamente, já que não se encaixa em nenhuma das regras acima. É um caso "ambíguo" para o compilador, e portanto, ele não irá inserir o ponto e vírgula.

É possível entender o porquê com o seguinte código:

```js
const myArray22 = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

// Note que depois de `22`, `[` é um token válido.
const x = myArray22
[0];

console.log(x); // A
```

É possível confirmar que o caractere `[` não foi visto como um *offending token*, e portanto, um ponto e vírgula não foi inserido.

---

Esse é um dos exemplos entre diversos em que a [inserção automática de ponto e vírgula não é 100% precisa](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_syntax.html#asi-triggered-unexpectedly), e portanto, muitos recomendam que ele sempre deva ser utilizado. Ferramentas como o ESLint, com a regra [`semi`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi); ou o [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) podem te ajudar imensuravelmente com isso.

#### Referência

Recursos que usei enquanto elaborava essa resposta:

- [Capítulo 6.7](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_syntax.html#automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi) de JavaScript for impatient programmers;
- [ECMAScript Automatic Semicolon Insertion](https://codeburst.io/ecmascript-automatic-semicolon-insertion-50f09091e377).

Comment: Achei uma sacanagem o negativo na resposta. Como veio junto com um positivo na minha pode ser algum fã. Eu não apoio isso. Acho inclusive que essa resposta responde melhor a pergunta específica e acho a aceitação justa. E se alguém acha que foi eu que negativei eu posso até provar que não votei (não só com screenshot que dá pra fazer Photoshop :) ), eu posso fazer muita coisa que as pessoas não gostam, mas não negativo conteúdo bom.

Answer (score 11):

JavaScript optou por especificar na linguagem que o `;`, que significa o fim de um *statement*, poderia ser opcional no código. Ao contrário do que muitos pensam, não é que não precisa do ponto e vírgula, é que o compilador coloca para você.

Para o compilador conseguir fazer isto precisa de regras claras e não ambíguas onde colocar. Não é fácil fazer isso, é mais difícil ainda quando você acrescenta uma *feature* nova na linguagem (que acho que o caso foi justamente este, a chave antes era tratada como um caso que não deveria iniciar um novo *statement*, não podiam mudar isso pra não quebrar compatibilidade, aí criaram um caso que era necessário, e o erro aconteceu). Então nem sempre funciona bem, tem situação que o compilador não consegue colocar no lugar certo ou nem coloca onde deveria. Neste caso o que aconteceu foi isto:

```js
let a = 11; let b = 22 [a, b] = [b, a]; console.log(a, b);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/Swap.js).

Ele colocou em alguns lugares, mas não entendeu que a desestruturação era outro *statement*, então ficou como se fosse uma coisa só. Aí o erro ficou esquisito, pra ele o que tem ali é usar uma variável que ainda não foi definida porque a definição só ocorre no fim do *statement*, o que ainda não ocorreu quando usou a variável, `let b = 22 [a, b] = [b, a];` é apenas um *statement*. Isso [está documentado](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_access_lexical_declaration_before_init).

[Tem especificação de onde é inserido](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-rules-of-automatic-semicolon-insertion). Mas tem que olhar sempre a versão mais nova, porque isso pode mudar de versão para versão. Portanto pra você usar certo tem que ficar sempre cuidando disso, saber que versão está usando. Tente entender e veja se vale a pena decodificar tudo aquilo pra fazer certo em cada situação.

Você pode entender simplificadamente as regras e resolver para um caso, mas pode não acontecer para outros. Não é fácil manter a consistência.

Até aqui expliquei porque ocorre isso, agora vamos entender o rolo que as pessoas estão se metendo.

## Desconsidere que o `;` é opcional

Ora, não é mais fácil parar de ficar usando essas exceções e colocar o tal do `;` em todos os finais de *statement*? O que ganha em não colocar isso? O programador que acha que está tendo algum ganho porque não precisou bater o dedo em uma tecla ali realmente está na profissão errada. Dá mais trabalho fazer exceção do que pôr sempre, você tem que ficar pensando se está certo ou não. Algumas pessoas podem perder horas não entendendo o que está acontecendo. E pode não ser você, pode ser outra pessoa que dará manutenção e coloca algo que não funciona porque o código que já estava escrito está sem o *semicolon*.

Tratar algo como exceção durante a codificação gera carga cognitiva desnecessária. Você não precisa disto, não faça.

Infelizmente há uma onda de pessoas ensinando JS sem o `;`. Essas pessoas estão prestando um desserviço para todos. É um direito delas e azar de quem confia nessas pessoas. Só não digam que não tem gente avisando, e não sou apenas eu, a maioria dos bons profissionais fazem isso.

Cito anedoticamente [o caso da fogueira de Osasco](https://g1.globo.com/sp/sao-paulo/noticia/2019/07/10/prefeito-e-primeira-dama-de-osasco-tem-alta-12-dias-apos-explosao-de-fogueira.ghtml).

[image: Fogueira que explodiu em Osasco]

Por anos a pessoa fez fogueiras. Nunca estudou para isso, sempre deu certo e sempre foi sendo contratado por autoridades para fazer aquilo. E claro, por ser evento de autoridade se viram no direito de não consultar gente qualificada sobre o assunto como ocorre muito no Brasil (queria dizer que é só no setor público, mas é generalizado, não são todos, mas é comum brasileiro ter compromisso com o erro). Uma hora a fogueira explode. E só acontece porque há um misto de ignorância com arrogância.

As pessoas veem funcionando sem `;` e acham que é sempre assim, elas passam acreditar que não tem problema, e passam defender isso, até que explode.

Esse caso foi fácil e óbvio, mas tem caso que pode fazer a pessoa arrancar os cabelos tentando descobrir o que está acontecendo.

Curiosamente, até onde eu sei, Go faz o mesmo e tudo funciona, as regras são mais claras e o compilador consegue fazer em todo caso. Mas posso estar enganado ou ter se tornado obsoleto com novas versões, não sou usuário normal de Go.