# Como retornar valores com números em um array

Tags: javascript, array

Estou tentando realizar um cálculo de notas escolares com JavaScript
porém o resultado me retorna `NaN`.

Código:

```js
array_notas = [10, 9, 8, 7]

function calcularMedia(param) {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        var result = 0;
        result += param[i].value;
    }

        let media = result / 4

        if (media < 6)
            console.log(`Aluno reprovado! MÉDIA DO ALUNO => ${media}`)
        else {
            console.log(`Aluno aprovado! MÉDIA DO ALUNO => ${media} `)
        }
};

console.log(calcularMedia(array_notas))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Os índices de um array começam em zero](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessing_array_elements). Então se um array tem 4 elementos, os índices vão de 0 a 3. Mas no `for` você coloca `i <= 4`, então ele vai tentar acessar o índice 4, que não existe, então primeiro deve mudar a condição para `<` em vez de `<=`. E na verdade, o ideal é usar [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length), que pega o tamanho do array, assim você não precisa usar valores fixos, e o código funciona para arrays de qualquer tamanho (se você usar sempre `4` e o array tiver mais elementos, não vai pegar todos, e se o array tiver menos elementos, vai tentar acessar elementos que não existem; em ambos os casos o resultado estará errado).

Outro detalhe é que se o array contém números, basta fazer `param[indice]` para pegar o seu valor. Não precisa do atributo `value` (esse atributo é usado quando você pega o valor de um `input` HTML, mas no seu caso o array contém números, então não precisa do `value`).

Além disso, o `result = 0` deve ficar antes do `for`. Colocando-o dentro do `for`, você zera o valor toda hora, e o resultado final não é a soma das notas.

Por fim, a função não está retornando nada (ela imprime o resultado e não retorna nenhum valor), então não tem porque fazer `console.log` no resultado desta (se reparar, seu código imprime um `undefined` a mais, que é o resultado de imprimir o retorno inexistente da função). Na verdade eu mudaria a função para retornar o valor da média, e quem chama a função faz o que quiser com o resultado.

Então ficaria assim:

```js
let array_notas = [10, 9, 8, 7];

function calcularMedia(param) {
    let result = 0; // zera a variável antes do for, e não dentro dele
    for (let i = 0; i < param.length; i++) { // use param.length
        result += param[i]; // não use value
    }

    return result / param.length; // só retorne o valor e pronto
}

let media = calcularMedia(array_notas); // aqui você pega o retorno e faz o que quiser com ele
if (media < 6) {
    console.log(`Aluno reprovado! MÉDIA DO ALUNO => ${media}`);
} else {
    console.log(`Aluno aprovado! MÉDIA DO ALUNO => ${media} `);
}
```

Também coloquei ponto-e-vírgula no final das linhas (e removi um que era desnecessário, depois do `}` que fecha a função). Pode parecer "frescura", mas eu criei esse hábito para evitar [algumas situações bizarras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/432960/112052) que podem ocorrer se você não usa ponto-e-vírgula em todas as linhas (veja mais sobre o assunto [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3341/112052)).

Answer (score 1):

Está tentando acessar um valor da array que não existe (índice `[4]`) ao fazer `i <= 4`. Com isso está retornando `undefined`, e ao tentar somar `undefined` com algum valor irá resultar em `NaN`.

Altere para `i < 4` ou `i < param.length` (tamanho da array, se a array tiver tamanho variável).

Agora, o `var result = 0;` deve ficar fora do laço, senão ele será zerado a todo tempo.

```js
array_notas = [10, 9, 8, 7];

function calcularMedia(param) {
   var result = 0;
   for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      result += param[i];
   }
   let media = result / 4
   
   if (media < 6)
      console.log(`Aluno reprovado! MÉDIA DO ALUNO => ${media}`)
   else {
      console.log(`Aluno aprovado! MÉDIA DO ALUNO => ${media} `)
   }
};

console.log(calcularMedia(array_notas))
```