# Mudar caracteres de uma string, exceto os 4 últimos

Tags: javascript, string

A ideia da função é trocar os caracteres de uma `string` (menos os últimos 4 caracteres) por um `"#"`. Criei a função, mas acredito que eu esteja com problemas na lógica do código.

```
function criptografar(dados) {
    let result = ""
    if (dados.length > 4) {
        for (let index = 0; index >= dados.length - 4; index++) {
            result += dados.replace(dados[index], "#")
            return result
        }
    } else {
        return dados
    }
}

//let nome = "Alexandre"
//-> "#####ndre"
```

Comment: Às vezes, eu acho que o pessoal está exagerando em negativar perguntas aqui na stack overflow. A descrição do problema está clara, o problema é, em tese, reproduzível, etc. etc. Acrescente-se a isso que não houve qualquer justificativa do ponto negativo.

Comment: Realmente, uma dúvida honesta, tentei ser o mais claro possível. Pessoal pesa muito a mão, infelizmente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um dos problemas foi colocar a condição `index >= dados.length - 4`. Como `index` começa em zero, se `dados` tiver tamanho 10, por exemplo, a condição será falsa, pois zero não é maior ou igual a 6, então o `for` não executará nenhuma iteração.

Outro problema é que o `return` está dentro do `for`, então na primeira iteração ele já retornaria, sem iterar pelos demais caracteres.

---

De qualquer forma, não precisa usar `replace`, pois você só precisa ter uma quantidade de `#` igual ao tamanho da string menos 4.

Uma forma de fazer é preencher o resultado com `#` até `dados.length - 4`, e em seguida pegar os 4 últimos caracteres da string usando [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```js
function criptografar(dados) {
    let result = "";
    for (let index = 0; index < dados.length - 4; index++) {
        result += "#";
    }
    // juntar os # com os 4 últimos caracteres da string 
    return result + dados.slice(-4);
}

console.log(criptografar('Alexandre'));
console.log(criptografar('abcde'));
console.log(criptografar('ab'));
```

Se a string tiver 4 caracteres ou menos, não entra no `for`, e `slice` retorna a string inteira.

---

Outra alternativa é usar [`repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) para construir a string contendo os `#`:

```js
function criptografar(dados) {
    if (dados.length > 4) {
        return "#".repeat(dados.length - 4) + dados.slice(-4);
    }
    return dados;
}

console.log(criptografar('Alexandre'));
console.log(criptografar('abcde'));
console.log(criptografar('ab'));
```

Se o tamanho da string for maior que 4, crio uma string com "tamanho - 4" caracteres `#` concatenado com os 4 últimos caracteres. Se o tamanho for menor ou igual a 4, ele não entra no `if` e retorna a string inteira, sem modificações.

---

Também coloquei ponto-e-vírgula no final das linhas. Pode parecer "frescura", mas isso evita [algumas situações bizarras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/432960/112052) que podem ocorrer se você não usá-los (veja mais sobre isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3341/112052)).

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar [.padStart()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart), o que dispensa o uso do laço `for`:

```js
function criptografar(dados){
   if(dados.length > 4)
      return dados.slice(-4).padStart(dados.length, "#");
   return dados;
}

console.log(criptografar("Alexandre"));
console.log(criptografar("Alex"));
console.log(criptografar("Alexa"));
```