# Usar ou não usar ponto-e-vírgula no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, estilo-de-codificação

Sou programador há pouco tempo e comecei agora a utilizar muitos frameworks e bibliotecas JavaScript. Como tenho maior conhecimento em Java trago alguns hábitos da linguagem como o usar o `;`, que sou habituado a utilizar, mas vejo que a maioria dos programadores não utiliza, aí fiquei na duvida: é certo ou errado usar? Por convenção se usa ou não se usa? Particularmente gosto de usar.

Comment: *"mais vejo que a maioria dos programadores não utiliza"* não sei onde está vendo isso, os que conheço usam, e não são poucos... isso me parece uma percepção sua. Eu sempre uso e deixa o código limpo e claro

Comment: Complementando a duplicada sugerida acima: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/432960/112052

Comment: Droga, estava respondendo, agora, vou ter que responder lá :D A minha ficará no fim pra sempre (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/447654/101, ela está um pouco mais adequada para esse contexto daqui, eu cortei a parte que eu contestava a afirmação feita na pergunta porque lá não faz sentido, mas ia na mesma linha do @RicardoPontual).