# Como coloco uma condicional dentro de um .forEach() no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, foreach

Estou fazendo um *scrapping* em um site que organiza os itens com uma tag `<a>`, no entanto estou recebendo vários valores com `null`.

Como posso colocar uma condicional para evitar esses valores `null` no retorno?

```
const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const medicines = []
    document.querySelectorAll('div > div > div > div > div > a')
            .forEach(
                medicine => if(medicine.getAttribute('title')!== null){
                    medicines.push(medicine.getAttribute('title'))
                    }
                )
    return medicines
  })
```

Comment: Tem várias formas, mas por que não usa um `for` normal que é muito mais fácil fazer isto?^Não é culpa sua, é que tem gente ensinando errado por aí, mas esse código não tem ganho algum fazendo assim, pelo contrário, só há problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem como utilizar uma condição `if` logo após o operador `=>`.

Quando você declara uma `arrow function` sem abrir o escopo utilizando chaves, você precisa declarar uma expressão com um retorno. Como `if` não tem retorno, ele não é um código válido.

Soluções seriam:

Abrir o escopo -

```
document.querySelectorAll('div > div > div > div > div > a')
    .forEach(medicine => {
        if(medicine.getAttribute('title') !== null ) {
            medicines.push(medicine.getAttribute('title'))
        }
    })
```

Utilizar uma expressão -

```
document.querySelectorAll('div > div > div > div > div > a')
    .forEach(medicine => medicine.getAttribute('title') !== null && medicines.push(medicine.getAttribute('title')))
```

Esse segundo exemplo funciona porque as condições lógicas `and` e `or` funcionam com "curto-circuito". Se a primeira expressão da condição for `false` seguido de um `&&`, a segunda expressão nem será executada, pois a esse ponto já é claro que o resultado da condição será `false`.

Answer (score 1):

A melhor maneira de fazer isso é usando um `.reduce`. Dessa maneira podes a cada iteração verificar se o `medicine` existe e juntá-lo ao array ou não.

Uma sugestão seria:

```js
const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const anchors = [...document.querySelectorAll('div > div > div > div > div > a')];
  return anchors.reduce((arr, anchor) => {
    const medicine = anchor.getAttribute('title');
    return medicine ? arr.concat(medicine) : arr;
  }, [])
});
```

Outra alternativa seria corrigir o erro de sintaxe que tens no teu código. Não podes ter um `if` diretamente dessa maneira depois de `=>`. Mas podias fazer assim:

```js
const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const medicines = []
  document.querySelectorAll('div > div > div > div > div > a')
    .forEach(
      medicine => medicine.getAttribute('title') && medicines.push(medicine.getAttribute('title'))
    )
  return medicines;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Só para deixar registrado, você não precisa necessariamente de [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) ou [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), pois dá para percorrer os elementos encontrados por [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) com um [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of):

```js
const medicines = [];
for (const a of document.querySelectorAll('div > div > div > div > div > a')) {
    if (a.getAttribute('title') !== null) {
        medicines.push(a.getAttribute('title'));
    }
}
console.log(medicines); // ["title1", "title2", ""]
```

```html
<div><div><div><div><div>
  <a title="title1"></a>
  <a href="semtitle.html"></a>
  <a title="title2"></a>
  <a href="#title-vazio" title=""></a>
</div></div></div></div></div>
```

Se bem que neste caso ele também está considerando o último `<a>`, que tem o atributo `title`, mas seu valor é uma string vazia. Não ficou claro se é para incluí-lo ou não, mas caso não seja, você pode mudar para `if (a.getAttribute('title'))` (pois [strings vazias são consideradas `false`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/271693/112052), então se o `title` for vazio, não entrará no `if`).

Outra alternativa para desconsiderar o `title` vazio é colocar esta condição no próprio seletor:

```js
const medicines = [];
// pegar somente tags "a" que tem title e o valor não é vazio
for (const a of document.querySelectorAll('div > div > div > div > div > a[title]:not([title=""])')) {
    medicines.push(a.getAttribute('title'));
}
console.log(medicines); // ["title1", "title2"]
```

```html
<div><div><div><div><div>
  <a title="title1"></a>
  <a href="semtitle.html"></a>
  <a title="title2"></a>
  <a href="#title-vazio" title=""></a>
</div></div></div></div></div>
```

---

Também coloquei ponto-e-vírgula no final das linhas. Pode parecer "frescura", mas isso evita [algumas situações bizarras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/432960/112052) que podem ocorrer se você não usá-los (veja mais sobre isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3341/112052)).