# Tarefa observa não executa corretamente

Tags: javascript, gulp

```
const sass = require('gulp-sass')
const gulp = require('gulp')

let caminho = `scss/**/*.scss`

gulp.task('scss', () => {
    return gulp.src(caminho)
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
})

gulp.task('observa', () => {
    return gulp.watch((caminho, ['scss']))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Note na linha abaixo:

> ```
> return gulp.watch((caminho, ['scss']))
> ```

Você está utilizando o operador vírgula, que recebe precedência sobre a separação dos argumentos da função já que você está utilizando um grupo de parênteses extra.

De acordo com a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operador_Virgula), o operador vírgula avalia todas as expressões entre elas, da esquerda para a direita, e retorna o valor da última delas.

Portanto, vamos ver o que você está passando para o primeiro argumento de `watch`:

```js
const caminho = `scss/**/*.scss`;
console.log((caminho, ['scss']));
```

Note que, apesar de `caminho` estar sendo avaliada, somente `['scss']` será retornada, já que é a última expressão entre as vírgulas.

Para resolver, simplesmente retire os parênteses internos para denotar a sintaxe de aplicação de função, em que N argumentos são separados por vírgulas:

```
return gulp.watch(caminho, ['scss']);
```

---

Apesar de não ser a causa do seu problema, também coloquei ponto e vírgula no final das linhas. Pode parecer "frescura", mas criei esse hábito para evitar [algumas situações bizarras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/432960/69296) que podem ocorrer se você não utilizar o ponto e vírgula em todas as linhas (veja mais sobre o assunto [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3341/69296)).