# Express - Sugestão de experiência, como lidar com esse tipo de repetição de código

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Ando estudando a biblioteca (Express) e a linguagem (JavaScript), mas esse tipo de repetição abaixo acaba me incomodando e. Gostaria de saber o que vocês fariam na situação para reduzir a repetição de código.

Este é um middleware que estou fazendo para uma rota e, se reparar, há uma seção em que verifico o `username`, `password`, `email`, `fullName` e `birthDate`, que retornam exatamente a mesma coisa, porém com o nome do modelo alterado. Acabei gastando 5 linhas para fazer isso.

A questão é: Existe alguma forma para se reduzir essa repetição de código?

```
module.exports = {
register: async (req, res) => {
        const { 
            username,
            password,
            email,
            fullName,
            birthDate
         } = req.body

         if (!username) return res.json({error: 'Username not found.'})
         if (!password) return res.json({error: 'Password not found.'})
         if (!email) return res.json({error: 'Email not found.'})
         if (!fullName) return res.json({error: 'Full name not found.'})
         if (!birthDate) return res.json({error: 'Birthdate not found.'})

         const userEmailExists = await userService.fetch( { email } ) ? true : false
         const userNameExists = await userService.fetch( { username } ) ? true : false

         if (userEmailExists) return res.json({error: 'User email already exists.'})
         if (userNameExists) return res.json({error: 'Username already exists.'})

         const user = await userService.create({ username, password, email, fullName, birthDate })

         user.password = undefined

         return res.status(200).json(user)
         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, em relação à repetição da "validação", você pode fazer algo como [sugerido na outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/480312/69296):

```
['username', 'password', 'email', 'fullName', 'birthDate'].forEach((key) => {
  if (!req.body[key]) return res.json({ error: `${key} not found.` });
});
```

No entanto, essa abordagem, embora extremamente válida, é um pouco limitada, uma vez que você envia uma mensagem de erro com a exata chave do objeto, o que pode destoar um pouco da mensagem original. Comparando a mensagem de erro a ser recebida por `fullName` vazio, temos:

- Para `fullName` vazio no código original:

  ```
  Full name not found.
  ```
- Para `fullName` vazio no código acima, que usa a própria chave na mensagem de erro:

  ```
  fullName not found.
  ```

<sup>Pode-se contornar essa diferença da mensagem utilizando um array de objetos, mas será que realmente vale a pena?</sup>

Além disso, percebe-se que você tem campos que exigem uma validção mais precisa, como `email` e `birthDate`. Desse modo, pode valer mais a pena procurar por bibliotecas de validação que já te dão isso pronto. Exemplos comumente utilizados são `yup` ou `joi` (pesquise no NPM).

Não obstante, se a única coisa que você deseja fazer é verificar a presença das propriedades no objeto, o código sugerido é totalmente válido.

---

Um outro ponto de importante menção que pode ser melhorado é este:

> ```
> const userEmailExists = await userService.fetch( { email } ) ? true : false
> const userNameExists = await userService.fetch( { username } ) ? true : false
> ```

Não há necessidade de utilizar um operador ternário aí. Não chega a ser sequer necessário converter para tipo booleano explicitamente (com a dupla negação `!!` ou construtor `Boolean`), já que o próprio `if` faz isso por você. Portanto, somente o seguinte já é suficiente:

```js
if (await userService.fetch({ email }))
  return res.json({ error: 'User email already exists.' });

if (await userService.fetch({ username }))
  return res.json({ error: 'Username already exists.' });
```

---

Por fim, sugiro utilizar ponto e vírgula no final de cada *statement*. Pode parecer "frescura" e sei que o JavaScript "aceita" o código sem ponto e vírgula e "funciona", mas isso evita algumas situações bizarras que podem ocorrer se você não os usar, como [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169596) e [esta](/q/432960) (veja mais sobre isso [aqui](/q/3341)).

Um exemplo real que poderia acontecer. Dependendo de onde você colocasse o código a seguir (que foi sugerido):

```
['username', 'password', 'email', 'fullName', 'birthDate'].forEach((key) => {
  if (!req.body[key]) return res.json({error: `${key} not found.`});
});
```

Sem ponto e vírgula no resto do código (ou no início da abertura do array — `;[`), você provavelmente veria o problema. Demonstro abaixo.

```js
console.log(1)

[1, 2, 3].forEach((num) => {
  console.log(num)
})
```

Comment: Luiz, que dicas sensacionais!
Isso com toda certeza supre minha dificuldade, muito obrigado!

Você conhece algum material de design patterns em programação funcional? 
Cara curti muito a simplicidade dessa código!

Comment: Nada do que foi comentado aqui tem muito a ver com programação funcional, mas uma referência excelente para saber mais sobre como o JavaScript funciona é este excelente livro: “JavaScript for inpatient programmers”. Se você quiser aprender programação funcional (de fato), sugiro ir para uma linguagem mais voltada a esse paradigma, como Haskell. Aí depois você volta pro JS e aplica os conceitos que aprendeu.

Answer (score 2):

```
[username,password,email,fullName,birthDate].forEach(key => {
  if (!req.body[key]) { return res.json({error: `${key} not found`}) }
});
```

Comment: Cuidado que, como o código do AP não utiliza ponto e vírgula, dependendo de onde for colocado, esse código pode causar um erro. Não é _exatamente_ a mesma coisa, mas as respostas desta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/432960/69296) dão uma ideia do porquê. Além disso, você não deveria ter utilizado os itens do _array_ como strings?