# Existe mais de uma forma de usar o "if"?

Tags: javascript, if, sintaxe

```js
const sequence = {
    _id: 1,
    get id() { return this._id++ }
}

const produtos = {}

function salvarProduto(produto) {
    if (!produto.id) produto.id = sequence.id
    produtos[produto.id] = produto
    return produto
}
```

A minha dúvida esta no `if` da função `salvarProduto()`. Achei que toda função fosse criada com esse padrão `if (expresao) {}`m mas nesse exemplo não tem chaves, por que?

Comment: Quano o if (não só o if) tiver somente uma instrução pode ser utilizado sem chaves.

Comment: As chaves `{}` são para denotar um bloco de código. Se existem várias instruções em múltiplas linhas elas devem estar envoltas entre chaves. 

Se há uma instrução apenas ou mais de uma em uma única linha então você pode fazer essa variação `if(condicao) instrucao1; instrucao2;`

Comment: @GeekSilva Essa informação não está correta: `if(condicao) instrucao1; instrucao2;` vai sempre executar a  `instrucao2`. Só a `instrucao1` está abrangida pelo `if`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## O que é o `if`

A primeira coisa que deve entender que o `if` não é uma função, é um comando da linguagem (isso pode ser visto mais em [O que são statements e operadores?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173379/101) e [Qual a diferença entre funções e procedimentos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122429/101), ainda que o ideal seja uma pergunta que peça a diferença entre *statement* e expressão, mas não tem).

Há uma confusão que algumas pessoas fazem por causa dos parênteses obrigatórios da expressão condicional. Eles não são os mesmos parênteses que se usa em funções, porque isso recomenda-se colocar junto do identificador em uma função  `funcao()` e separado em um *statement* padrão da linguagem (`if (condicao)`), fica mais legível.

Outro erro comum é que as pessoas acham que deve ter uma comparação ali dentro da condição. Na verdade ali cabe qualquer expressão possível da linguagem, desde que o resultado final seja um valor booleano para o comando `if` poder decidir se ele executará um comando a seguir. Exemplo disso em [Atribuir uma expressão a uma variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44741/101).

## Chaves

A forma mais simples é ele executar apenas um comando por isso o normal é não ter chaves.

A estrutura do comando toda tem três partes. Você tem a palavra que define o comando (`if`), a expressão condicional (o que está entre parênteses) e depois o comando que deve ser executado condicionalmente.

Tecnicamente tem dois *statements* aí, mas o `if` é uma *statement* incompleto e precisa de outro para executar adequadamente, por isso ele nunca termina com `;`.

Acontece que em muitas situações é necessário executar vários comandos juntos **dependendo** da condição. Para estabelecer que vários comandos juntos são uma coisa só você usa uma sintaxe de **bloco de comando**. Essa sintaxe são chaves. A junção de vários *statements* se transformam em um só pelas chaves. Claro que continuará existindo vários, mas para o `if` só o bloco é que conta.

Note que o bloco nada tem a ver com o `if`, por acaso o bloco pode ser usado ali, mas não é algo ligado ao `if`. Quando você coloca as chaves todos aqueles comandos se comportam como se fosse uma coisa só e é essa coisa só que será executada se a condição for verdadeira.

Obviamente as chaves podem ser usadas para criar um bloco de apenas um *statement* (comando), algumas pessoas fazem assim, outras não. É uma questão de gosto neste caso. Só não é gosto quando tem várias linhas que pertencem ao mesmo bloco. Veja a diferença:

```js
if (false)
    console.log(1);
    console.log(2);
```

Note que apenas o primeiro comando após o `if` pertence a ele o segundo não, ele é isolado. É uma forma ruim de escrever porque a indentação engana, mas ela não tem relevância em JS, só as chaves podem criar um bloco.

Agora veja com chaves ambos pertencem ao `if`:

```js
if (false) {
    console.log(1);
    console.log(2);
}
```

Tem até um fenômeno chamado *dangling else* sobre isso. O que acha que acontece aqui?

```js
if (false)
    if (true)
        console.log(1);
else
    console.log(2);
```

Parece estranho, né? O `else` pertence ao `if` mais perto dele e não ao que parece. Com as chaves não tem perigo:

```js
if (false) {
    if (true) {
        console.log(1);
    } else {
        console.log(2);
    }
}
```

Mas se indentar certo ainda fica legível:

```js
if (false)
    if (true)
        console.log(1);
    else
        console.log(2);
```

Por isso que eu dou valor à indentação. A confusão só ocorre em código mal escrito.

## Bloco de comandos

As chaves podem ser usadas em várias situações, como depois do `do`, `while`, `for`, a função, ou até mesmo sem nada. Sim, o bloco pode vir sozinho só para criar escopo para variáveis. Raro ser útil em JavaScript (menos ainda se não usar `let`), mas poderia usar. O que espera que aconteça?

```js
let x = 1;
{
   let x = 2;
   console.log(x);
}
console.log(x);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/IfBlock.js).

## Estilo

Eu adotei o estilo de quando é uma linha eu não uso chaves, mas o comando deve vir obrigatoriamente na mesma linha do `if`, se for lingo demais e quiser por na outra linha, aí obriga por chaves. E se tiver um bloco claro que sempre haverá chaves.

Vejo alguma vantagem em usar as chaves sempre mesmo para uma linha, já usei muito, mas a experiência me mostrou que não era necessário, não tive problemas. O que eu acho estranho é colocar uma linha só e as chaves tudo amontoado na mesma linha, se vai usar chaves então faça parecer um bloco, mesmo que só tenha uma linha nesse bloco.

Jamais pode colocar mais de um *statement* como uma coisa só na mesma linha. Cada `;` é um `statement`, por isso acho que o `;` deve ser obrigatório, [veja sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/447654/101).

## Conclusão

Em certo aspecto programar é como montar Lego. Você tem várias peças que podem se encaixar, use a criatividade para juntar as peças de forma que dá encaixe. Algumas pessoas têm dificuldade de programar porque elas não entendem isso, e só seguem receitas de bolo, elas só copiam o que viram montado por outras pessoas. Entenda o que é cada peça da linguagem e poderá criar brinquedos melhores.

Comment: Ótima colocação sobre as chaves indicarem blocos de comando! No fim das contas, o if só executa a próxima instrução de qualquer forma (que com as chaves a "próxima instrução" é um bloco de instruções)! Muito válida também a questão da indentação que o pessoal muitas vezes não compreende como é importante!

Comment: @GuilhermeC.Dalleprane legal ver quem aprecia as cosias corretas, o detalhamento.

Answer (score 6):

Sim. No Javascript, quando você não coloca chaves, apenas a próxima instrução é executada. As chaves são necessárias apenas quando se deseja executar mais de uma instrução condicionada pelo if.

A instrução:

```js
    let a = 1
    if (a == 1) 
        alert("É verdadeiro!")
    else
        alert("É falso!")
```

É o mesmo que:

```js
let a = 1
if (a == 1) {
    alert("É verdadeiro!")
} else {
    alert("É falso!")
}
```

Mas... a instrução:

```js
let a = 1
if (a == 1) {
    alert("Executa quando a é igual a 1")
    alert("Executa novamente quando a é igual a 1")
}
```

Não é o mesmo que:

```js
let a = 1
if (a == 2)
    alert("Executa apenas se a é igual a 1")

alert("Executará independendo do valor de a")
```

No caso acima, o segundo alert sempre será executado (repare também que a identação correta do segundo alert é seguindo a identação do if e não da instrução que está dentro dele. Outra forma de escrever, seria como no exemplo da pergunta, colocando a instrução logo na frente do if, assim:

```js
let a = 1
if (a == 2) alert("Executa apenas se a é igual a 1")
   
alert("Executará independendo do valor de a")
```

Answer (score 4):

A instrução `if` geralmente é seguida por chaves. No entanto, você pode omiti-las se quiser executar somente uma expressão caso a condição seja avaliada como verdadeira:

```js
if (true) console.log(1); // 1
if (false) console.log(2);
```

Note que terminamos com um ponto e vírgula. Se usarmos diversos *statements* em uma mesma linha, separados por ponto e vírgula, somente o primeiro estaria na atuação do `if`, veja:

```js
if (false) console.log(1); console.log(2); console.log(3);
```

Por isso eu sempre prefiro usar as chaves, elas tornam mais claro o que está sendo feito. O código acima é equivalente a este:

```js
if (false) {
  console.log(1);
}

console.log(2);
console.log(3);
```

Para saber mais, veja [este documento](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_control-flow.html#if).